# Highchart custom label doesn't seem to work with data:image/png;base64

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to use a custom label for the labels but it doesn't seem to render if the source of a image is a `data:image/png;base64`.
Searching on this [online](https://medium.com/@ians/rendering-svgs-as-images-directly-in-react-a26615c45770) it's mentioned that I should use `renderToStaticMarkup` and/or `encodeURIComponent`, but this is also not working.

See code example below :

```
const graphOptions : Highcharts.Options = {
        chart: {
            width: 500,
            height: 250,
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Votes'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '',
            pointFormat: '{point.y} votes by ',
            footerFormat: '{point.key}',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{ 
            type: 'column',
            name: 'votes',
            data: votesData
        }],
        xAxis: {
            categories: addressData,
            labels: {
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return renderToStaticMarkup(<span>
                        {<Avatar
                        src={makeBlockie("0x1e52C0887bc0F752368dFb80974ec988Ab40AED3")}
                        size={20}
                        alt={'0x1e52C0887bc0F752368dFb80974ec988Ab40AED3'}
                      /> }
                      </span>)
                }
            }                
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={graphOptions} />
        </div>
    )
```

`makeBlockie` is used for generating blocky identicons as base64 encoded PNGs

Comment: Take a look at this topic: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40901 according to the information you should return an HTML element in the formatter callback

Comment: yes and if I return this `return '<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />'` it works. 
But if I use this `return '<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />' it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure that your src path is correct? It should work locally, but if you want to make it work on production, you will need to upload this image to the server and change the src path.

Comment: yes I am sure that the src path is correct, if I add the image outside the Graph it is displayed. It doesn't work locally, haven't tried it out on a server.

Comment: Interesting, try to add some basic styling, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kv16mrca/

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ro5z96h3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for sharing a demo in the comments. It looks like a regression, I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16149

As a workaround you can use the last working version: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aLx4o7u3/

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.2.2/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the work-around. I am using 'highcharts-react-official' and there the workaround doesn't seem to work. Do you have any suggestions/workaround for 'highcharts-react-official'?

Comment: @LendlVerschoor you can use the workaround from the Github thread - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f1ve3y?file=index.js `Highcharts.AST.allowedReferences.push('data:')`